Using ngxTranslate with PrimeNG dropdown breaks after migrating from Angular v16 to v18
DESCRIPTION
I've just upgraded from Angular v16 to v18. All is working fine, except for the translation of my dropdown items. I'm using ngxTranslate for this, together with my own implementation of Option to allow me to work with dropdowns in an easy way. After upgrading Angular to v18 however, I'm getting the following error: "ERROR TypeError: items is not iterable" on options.model.ts -> super(...items)
This was working fine beforehand. I can confirm that the translation without the dropdown is working fine. When logging the constructor of Items, I'm noticing that the value of items is the numeric value 0.
filter.component.html
<p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="memberFilter.language" [options]="languages" showClear="true" i18n-placeholder
  placeholder="Selecteer een taal">
  <ng-template pTemplate="item" let-item>
    {{item.label | translate}}
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="selectedItem">
    {{item.label | translate}}
  </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>

filter.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-members-overview-filter',
  templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter.component.css']
})

export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {

  public languages: Options;

  constructor(public memberService: MemberService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.memberService.getAllLanguages().subscribe(
      (res: Options) => {
        this.languages = res;
        console.log(this.languages) // logs the languages as defined in data.json -> [0: Object { value: 0, label: "member.languages.NL" }, 1: Object { value: 1, label: "member.languages.FR" }, ...]
      });
  }
}

member.service.ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MemberService {
  getAllLanguages(): Observable<Options> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      observer.next(new Options(data.member.languages))
    })
  }
}

options.model.ts
export interface Option {
  value: any
  label: string
}

declare global {
  interface Options {
    getLabel
  }
}

export class Options extends Array<Option> {

  public constructor(items: Array<Option>) {
    console.log(items) // this logs the value 0 (as number) when opening the dropdown
    super(...items)
  }

  getLabel(value: any): string {
    return this.find(x => x.value === value).label
  }
}

data.json
{
  "member": {
    "languages": [
      {
        "value": 0,
        "label": "member.languages.NL"
      },
      {
        "value": 1,
        "label": "member.languages.FR"
      },
      {
        "value": 2,
        "label": "member.languages.DE"
      },
      {
        "value": 3,
        "label": "member.languages.??"
      }
    ], 
  }
}

nl.json
{
  "member": {
    "languages": 
      {
        "NL": "Nederlands",
        "FR": "Frans",
        "DE": "Duits",
        "??": "Onbekend"
      }  
   }
}

package.json
{
  "name": "client-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~18.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~18.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~18.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~18.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~18.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~18.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~18.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~18.1.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^7.0.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "angularx-qrcode": "^15.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "i18n-json-to-xlsx-converter": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "ngx-json-viewer": "^3.1.0",
    "ngx-translate": "^0.0.1-security",
    "notyf": "^3.10.0",
    "primeflex": "^3.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^7.0.0",
    "primeng": "^17.18.4",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.14.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~18.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~18.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~18.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^18.1.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.11",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.43",
    "codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.15",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^5.5.3"
  }
}

                                                                                             


problem is in data.member.languages try a console.log and see if it has an array value!
